# pgfgantt create a blank page

Tags: babel, pgfgantt, translator

I have this code that create a Gantt chart using `pgfgantt` package. I have two problems :

1. This code create two pages (the first is blank)
2. There's untranslated words (e.g. Today)

Here's the code :

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
%\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}
\usepackage[frenchb]{translator}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{lscape}
\definecolor{barblue}{RGB}{153,204,254}
\definecolor{groupblue}{RGB}{51,102,254}
\definecolor{linkred}{RGB}{165,0,33}
\sffamily
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{tikzpicture} % optional
   \begin{ganttchart}[x unit=2mm, 
                      y unit chart=1cm, 
                      time slot format=isodate, 
                      %compress calendar,
                      vgrid=*{5}{dotted},
                      today=2014-04-27,
                      newline shortcut=true,
                      title/.append style={fill=blue!20, drop shadow},
                      title label font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white},
                      title label node/.append style={below=-1.6ex},
                      title left shift=.05,
                      title right shift=-.05,
                      title height=1,
                      bar/.append style={draw=none, fill=black!63},
                      bar label node/.append style={align=center, font=\tiny},
                      bar incomplete/.append style={fill=barblue},
                      bar height=.4,
                      bar label font=\normalsize\color{black!50},
                      link/.style={-latex, draw=red, fill=red},
                     ]
                      {2014-04-14}{2014-07-11}
   \gantttitlecalendar{month=name} \\ 

    \ganttbar[progress=100]{Mise en place\ganttalignnewline de environnement\ganttalignnewline du travail}{2014-04-14}{2014-04-15} \\

    \ganttbar[progress=100]{Spécifications}{2014-04-15}{2014-04-17} \\

    \ganttbar[progress=70]{Comprendre et\ganttalignnewline analyser le\ganttalignnewline code existant}{2014-04-18}{2014-05-03} \\

    \ganttbar[progress=60]{Analyse des \ganttalignnewline besoins de la\ganttalignnewline plate-forme MEANS}{2014-04-18}{2014-05-07} \\

    \ganttbar[progress=30]{Conception des \ganttalignnewline services web}{2014-04-21}{2014-05-24} \\

    \ganttbar[progress=80]{Conception de \ganttalignnewline l'API Java}{2014-04-25}{2014-05-07} \\

    \ganttbar[progress=0]{Implémentation des\ganttalignnewline services web}{2014-05-26}{2014-06-15} \\

    \ganttbar[progress=0]{Tests des\ganttalignnewline services web}{2014-05-26}{2014-06-17} \\

    \ganttbar[progress=0]{Implémentation de\ganttalignnewline l'API Java}{2014-06-03}{2014-06-20}\\

    \ganttbar[progress=0]{Tests de\ganttalignnewline l'API Java}{2014-06-03}{2014-06-21} \\

    \ganttbar[progress=0]{Rédaction de\ganttalignnewline la documentation}{2014-06-22}{2014-06-25} \\

    %\ganttbar[]{Maintenance}{2014-06-26}{2014-07-11}

    \ganttlink[link type=f-s]{elem4}{elem6}
    \ganttlink[link type=f-s]{elem1}{elem2}
     \ganttlink[link type=s-s]{elem6}{elem7}
      \ganttlink[link type=s-s]{elem8}{elem9}


   \end{ganttchart}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

I'm new in `pgfgantt`, I will appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Please add `\usetikzlibrary{shadows}` so your code is compilable. After this addition you'll get a warning `Overfull \vbox (39.08493pt too high) has occurred while \output is active` so your table is too large and it's moved to the second page. Reduce the height of your table.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina could you make it an answer please, so I choose it like an answer. Do you have an idea about the untranslated words?

Comment: I've provided an answer below. I also show how to solve the problem with "TODAY".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you process your document you get two warnings:

```
Overfull \hbox (39.01761pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 73--74
[][]

Overfull \vbox (39.19604pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
```

which indicate that your chart is too big for the current page layout; in particular, since it is too high, it is moved to the second page. One way to prevent this is to slightly change the values for xunit and y unit chart. I found that using

```
x unit=1.8mm, 
y unit chart=0.87cm,
```

solves the problem.

There's also a third warning, not relevant to the issue discussed, about not using the `OT1` font encoding with `frenchlb`; you need to switch to the Cork encoding

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

I guess you didn't include this in your MWE since it was not essential to the problem discussed.

Regarding the problem with "TODAY", the string used for the `today` key is controlled by the key `today label` (default value=TODAY), so you can use the `today label` and/or `today label font` keys to have the desired string with the desired format; in my example code I used

```
today label=aujourd'hui,
today label font=\scshape,
```

You have also to change the text of link labels by using this code :

```
\setganttlinklabel{s-s}{Début \`a d\'ebut (DD)}
\setganttlinklabel{f-s}{Fin \`a d\'ebut (FD)}
```

and add this code to `ganttchart` options to :

```
progress label text = {\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0, verbatim]{#1}\% fait}
```

bit you can change those settings according to your needs.

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
%\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}
\usepackage[frenchb]{translator}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage{lscape}
\definecolor{barblue}{RGB}{153,204,254}
\definecolor{groupblue}{RGB}{51,102,254}
\definecolor{linkred}{RGB}{165,0,33}
\sffamily

\setganttlinklabel{s-s}{Début \`a d\'ebut (DD)}
\setganttlinklabel{f-s}{Fin \`a d\'ebut (FD)}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{tikzpicture} % optional
   \begin{ganttchart}[x unit=1.8mm, 
                      y unit chart=0.87cm, 
                      time slot format=isodate, 
                      %compress calendar,
                      vgrid=*{5}{dotted},
                      today=2014-04-27,
                      today label=aujourd'hui,
                      today label font=\scshape,
                      newline shortcut=true,
                      title/.append style={fill=blue!20, drop shadow},
                      title label font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white},
                      title label node/.append style={below=-1.6ex},
                      title left shift=.05,
                      title right shift=-.05,
                      title height=1,
                      bar/.append style={draw=none, fill=black!63},
                      bar label node/.append style={align=center, font=\tiny},
                      bar incomplete/.append style={fill=barblue},
                      bar height=.4,
                      bar label font=\normalsize\color{black!50},
                      link/.style={-latex, draw=red, fill=red},
                      progress label text = {\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0, verbatim]{#1}\% fait},
                     ]
                      {2014-04-14}{2014-07-11}
   \gantttitlecalendar{month=name} \\ 

    \ganttbar[progress=100]{Mise en place\ganttalignnewline de environnement\ganttalignnewline du travail}{2014-04-14}{2014-04-15} \\

    \ganttbar[progress=100]{Spécifications}{2014-04-15}{2014-04-17} \\

    \ganttbar[progress=70]{Comprendre et\ganttalignnewline analyser le\ganttalignnewline code existant}{2014-04-18}{2014-05-03} \\

    \ganttbar[progress=60]{Analyse des \ganttalignnewline besoins de la\ganttalignnewline plate-forme MEANS}{2014-04-18}{2014-05-07} \\

    \ganttbar[progress=30]{Conception des \ganttalignnewline services web}{2014-04-21}{2014-05-24} \\

    \ganttbar[progress=80]{Conception de \ganttalignnewline l'API Java}{2014-04-25}{2014-05-07} \\

    \ganttbar[progress=0]{Implémentation des\ganttalignnewline services web}{2014-05-26}{2014-06-15} \\

    \ganttbar[progress=0]{Tests des\ganttalignnewline services web}{2014-05-26}{2014-06-17} \\

    \ganttbar[progress=0]{Implémentation de\ganttalignnewline l'API Java}{2014-06-03}{2014-06-20}\\

    \ganttbar[progress=0]{Tests de\ganttalignnewline l'API Java}{2014-06-03}{2014-06-21} \\

    \ganttbar[progress=0]{Rédaction de\ganttalignnewline la documentation}{2014-06-22}{2014-06-25} \\

    %\ganttbar[]{Maintenance}{2014-06-26}{2014-07-11}

    \ganttlink[link type=f-s]{elem4}{elem6}
    \ganttlink[link type=f-s]{elem1}{elem2}
     \ganttlink[link type=s-s]{elem6}{elem7}
      \ganttlink[link type=s-s]{elem8}{elem9}


   \end{ganttchart}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What about the others words (complete, start-to-finish). I geuss I will translate them using translator package, but I don't know the keys to use.

Comment: I have found the solution and edited your answer.